# Android Settings.System.putInt() method failing

Tags: java, android

When running

`Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "aod_mode", 0);`

I am given the error of "You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings." Anyone know how to fix it? Android api 28

This is after checking

`Settings.System.canWrite(context);`

I have also included:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE\_SETTINGS"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE\_SECURE\_SETTINGS"/>`

Comment: why do you want it for sleep off ( on action ?

Comment: @errorau I've just been wanting to try create my own custom always on display scheduler for when notifications come in etc